# How to join two queries from two tables into one query in PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm starting out to learning php and I wrote 2 queries to fetch data from two tables.

Currently, these are my tables:

**food_vendors**

```
 ID     Name         Description  
 -----------------------------
 1      Vendor 1     testing
 2      Vendor 2     testing
 3      Vendor 3     testing
```

**food_vendor_menu**

```
 ID     VENDOR_ID   FOOD_NAME  
 -----------------------------
 1      1           Food 1
 2      1           Food 2
 3      2           Food 3
 4      2           Food 4
 5      3           Food 5
```

Each `vendor_id` in **food_vendor_menu** corresponds to the `id` in **food_vendors**. Therefore, Vendor 1 would have 2 food items, as well as Vendor 2, while Vendor 3 only has 1 food item.

Currently, I'm making 2 queries and looping through them like so:

```
$sql = "select * from food_vendors";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$jsonData = array();
$rowCount = $result->num_rows;
$index = 1;
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sqlnew = "select * from food_vendor_menu where vendor_id=" .$row['id']. "" ;

    $resultnew = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlnew) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $jsonData = array();
    $rowCountnew = $resultnew->num_rows;
    $indexnew = 1;
    $menuStrings = array();
    if ($rowCountnew >0)
    {
        while($rownew =mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultnew))
        {
            $menuStrings[$indexnew] = array("id" => $rownew['id'], "food_name" => $rownew['food_name']);

            ++$indexnew;
        }
    }

    echo '"item'.$index.'":';
    echo json_encode(array("id" => intval($row['id']), "name" => $row['name'], "description" => $row['description'],  "menu_items" =>$menuStrings));
    if ($rowCount != $index)
    {
        echo ',';
    }
    ++$index;
}

echo ' }';
```

This produces the following output:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vendor 1",
        "description": "testing":,
        "menu_items": {
            "1": {
                "id": "1",
                "food_name": "Food 1"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": "2",
                "food_name": "Food 2"
            }
        }
    },
    "item2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Vendor 2",
        "description": "testing"
        "menu_items": {
            "1": {
                "id": "3",
                "food_name": "Food 3"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": "4",
                "food_name": "Food 4"
            }
        }
    },
    "item3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Vendor",
        "description": "testing",
        "menu_items": {
            "1": {
                "id": "5",
                "food_name": "Food 5",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't believe this is the best way, and I like to produce the **same** output using only one query, so upon research, I try to learn and replaced the above code with the following, joining the 2 tables together:

```
$sql = "select * from food_vendor_menu s join food_vendors t on t.id=vendor_id" ;
$q = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$jsonData = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    if (isset( $row['vendor_id'] ) )
    {
        $index = 'item'.$row['vendor_id'].'';
        $jsonData[$index] = $row;
        unset( $jsonData[$index]['food_name'] );
        $jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = array();
        $jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = $row['food_name'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

The result of the output:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "id": "1",
        "vendor_id": "1",
        "name": "Vendor 1",
        "description": "testing",
        "menu_items": "Food 1"
    },
    "item2": {
        "id": "2",
        "vendor_id": "2",
        "name": "Vendor 2",
        "description": "testing",
        "menu_items": "Food 3"
    },
    "item3": {
        "id": "3",
        "vendor_id": "3",
        "name": "Vendor 3",
        "description": "testing",
        "menu_items": "Food 5"
    }
}
```

I know this is the better approach and more efficient, but as you can see from the output above, the `menu_items` array for Vendor 1 only has `Food 1`, but no `Food 2`. The same issue with the other 2 vendors. Also, I need to append the `vendor_id` to each menu item, not just food name.

I know where the issue is, I just don't know how to fix it, due to my limited knowledge of php at the moment.

Can someone assist?

**UPDATE:**

Following Joey's suggestion, I replaced:

```
$jsonData[$index] = $row
$jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = array();
$jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = $row['food_name'];
```

with:

```
if ( !isset( $jsonData[$index] ) )
{
    $jsonData[$index] = $row;
    $jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = array();
}
array_push($jsonData[$index]['menu_items'], $row['food_name']);
```

I get the following output:

```
"item1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Vendor 1",
        "description": "testing",
        "menu_items": ["Food 1", "Food 2"]
    }
```

However, I need to make each `Food 1`, `Food 2`, an array itself because I need to associate other data to each food item, like `id`, food price, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "select * from food_vendor_menu s join food_vendors t on t.id=vendor_id";
...
$jsonData[$index] = $row
...
$jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = array();
$jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = $row['food_name'];
```

Should something like:

```
$sql = "select s.id as food_id, s.food_name, s.vendor_id, t.name, t.description from food_vendor_menu s join food_vendors t on t.id=vendor_id";
...
if (!isset($jsonData[$index])) {
    $jsonData[$index] = $row;
    unset( $jsonData[$index]['food_id'], $jsonData[$index]['food_name'] );
    $jsonData[$index]['menu_items'] = array();
}
array_push($jsonData[$index]['menu_items'],
           array('id'=>$row['food_id'], 'food_name'=>$row['food_name']));
```

Comment: thanks but there still consist of one menu item for `Vendor 1` and `Vendor 2`, how do I loop through and get the other 2 menu items and add it to `menu_items`?

Comment: You're already looping through all the items, except that you're overwriting stuff that you've already stored. Answer edited.

Comment: thanks, I get the correct output now, however, there is still  the issue of being able to attach the `id` of each `food_name` to `menu_items` as seen in the above 1st output. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Then change `array_push($jsonData[$index]['menu_items'], $row['food_name']);` to $array_push($jsonData[$index]['menu_items'], array('id'=>$row['food_id']), 'food_name'=>$row['food_name'])); It may require you to change the sql a little to have field `food_id`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to change the SQL, as I'm still learning basics. Also, how is your code implementation compared to barudo in terms of efficiency?...I like to have the most optimized way to query the data as I'm pulling it from my iOS app.

Comment: Updated answers to provide a "concrete" solution. I am not very certain about the efficiency issue, given it is usually complicated. Though, @barudo's solution have some additional computation, e.g., string concatenation/split, group-by and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        t.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s.id, '%%',s.food_name) SEPARATOR '||') as menu_items
    FROM 
        food_vendor_menu s 
    JOIN
        food_vendors t 
    ON
        t.id=vendor_id
    GROUP BY
        s.vendor_id
    ";
```

Php processing

```
//create an array
$jsonData = array();
$count = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    //lets place the row...
    $jsonData['item'.$count] = $row;
    //lets edit the menu_items by exploding it....
    $menu_items = explode('||', $row['menu_items']);
    $jsonData['item'.$count]['menu_items'] = [];
    foreach($menu_items as $food_count => $food)
    {
        list($menu_id, $food_name) = explode('%%', $food);
        $menu_item = (object)['id'=>$menu_id, 'food_name'=>$food_name];
        $jsonData['item'.$count]['menu_items'][($food_count+1)] = $menu_item; 
    }
    $count++;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData); //output it as a JSON encoded data...
```

I think its better that the menu_items is represented in array form (enclosed in []) rather than objects (enclosed in {}).

Comment: upvoted for workable solution, but how is the efficiency of yours compares to @Joey Zhang?

Comment: First, starting with the result from the query - while loop: @Joey's will result into an `m x n` number of rows (m = menu_items per vendor and n = vendors). Whereas mine will result into `n` rows (vendors only). Second Loop: though not shown in @Joey's but if you implement it to get the `id for each menu_item`, a loop is needed to be implemented there that is the foreach loop in mine.

Comment: can you help me resolve another query issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477653/how-to-combine-multiple-sql-queries-into-one-to-output-as-json-in-php-code